# Could not find part of the file path

Tags: c#, filepath

I've come across [image: this error] which states that part of the file path cannot be found. I'm fairly new to coding, but is this mistake obvious?

[I've created the same application before off a USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czntq.png)

Which works fine, so quite confused as to why the application on my machine isn't.

[Error message itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd0Vg.png)

Update - thank you for the comments so far.

Comment: Well the error is saying your path is incorrect, check it and fix the error. We can't tell you where the error is since we don't know the correct path.

Comment: The directory `Image` likely doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the relative directory of \Images you want to change line 33 to:

`filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image"), fileName);`

You are missing the tilde '~' to make it relative.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but that didn't seem to work unfortunately. Same error is returned.

Comment: Can you confirm the location in the exception message exists?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too sure what you mean. I've shown the location of the exception in the first screenshot? Could you explain further?

Comment: Have you tried to navigate to the location using Windows? Just to ensure the location actually exists.

I'm trying to find out if a) the directory exists and b) you have permission to view the contents.

Comment: Yeah, it exists C:\Users\Joe\source\repos\RecreatedMediaOrganizer\RecreatedMediaOrganizer\Models\Image.cs - I've tested with "/Models/Image" included in the Sever MapPath function with no luck. That path is correct because I've used it in the working solution. Practically no change except the other is on a usb stick. This application is on my c drive.

Comment: I've fixed it. All sorted.

Comment: What was it? I'm very curious!

Comment: Well his comment said he has a path of `...\Image.cs` so a file `Image.cs` and not a directory of `Image`, so yeah...

Comment: Yeah, essentially I was confusing Image.cs with an Image directory. This meant I needed to create an Image folder in my solution. This enabled the image to be stored in the directory, then stored in the db.